# Installing Django with mod_wsgi in centos, ImportError: No module named os

Tags: django, centos, mod-wsgi

I have, this httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.hello2.ch
    DocumentRoot /home/django_www/hello
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/django_www/hardi/django.wsgi
    ErrorLog /var/www/django_www/hardi/error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/django_www/hardi/access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

## vi /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
128.178.131.89  www.hello2.ch
128.178.131.89  ohtersite.ch
```

python 2.5, mod_wsgi-2.5, /root/epd-5.1.0/lib/libpython2.5.so.1.0 : installed!

## ldd /root/epd-5.1.0/bin/python

```
libpython2.5.so.1.0 => /root/epd-5.1.0/lib/libpython2.5.so.1.0 (0x00002b1bb7333000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003da0600000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003d9fe00000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x0000003dadc00000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003da0200000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003d9fa00000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003d9f600000)
```

## echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

/root/epd-5.1.0/lib/

But when i try to load the webpage, i get the following error_log:

```
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
[Wed Aug 29 11:52:57 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Aug 29 11:52:57 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Aug 29 11:52:57 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Aug 29 11:52:57 2012] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 256 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Wed Aug 29 11:52:57 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 29 11:55:00 2012] [error] [client 66.249.72.187] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/app/webroot/w3
[Wed Aug 29 11:58:30 2012] [error] [client 66.249.72.187] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/app/webroot/w3
[Wed Aug 29 12:01:58 2012] [error] [client 66.249.72.187] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/app/webroot/w3
[Wed Aug 29 12:05:30 2012] [error] [client 66.249.72.187] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/app/webroot/w3
[Wed Aug 29 12:09:00 2012] [error] [client 66.249.72.187] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/app/webroot/w3
[Wed Aug 29 12:12:29 2012] [error] [client 66.249.72.187] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/app/webroot/w3
[Wed Aug 29 12:14:06 2012] [error] [client 178.33.137.225] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/app/webroot/w3
[Wed Aug 29 12:15:59 2012] [error] [client 66.249.72.187] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html/app/webroot/w3
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
....
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
[Wed Aug 29 12:17:47 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
[Wed Aug 29 12:17:47 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Aug 29 12:17:47 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Aug 29 12:17:47 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Aug 29 12:17:47 2012] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 256 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Wed Aug 29 12:17:47 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 29 12:18:01 2012] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Aug 29 12:18:01 2012] [error]   File "/var/www/django_www/hardi/django.wsgi", line 1, in <module>
[Wed Aug 29 12:18:01 2012] [error]     import os
[Wed Aug 29 12:18:01 2012] [error] ImportError: No module named os
```

Any idea, in how to make Django work with mod_wsgi, and how can i make it possible to match the first VirtualHost entry with www.hello2.ch webpage and all the others at the second VirtualHost entry?

Comment: Does the python shell open when you type `python` into the command line?

Comment: Hmmm. Okay, in the shell try `import os`. If you get the same import error then the problem is with your python installation, not mod_wsgi or django.

Comment: Just a hint (has nothing to do with your question tbh), but dont use python2.5 with mod_wsgi. There is a bug in python2.5 which leads to Error 500 pages here and there because of a memory allocation issue.

Comment: How does `/var/www/html/app/webroot/w3` figure into all of this?

Comment: @Jingo: so, i should better install another version of python and remove the 2.5.. ? In fact i've a static website hosted on the server and i don't this this changes will cause any trouble.

Comment: @IamChuckB : in fact "w3" is a symbolic link that points to "../../w3" that it doesn't exist!

Comment: You cant remove 2.5 from centos, it will break centos os commands like yum. But you can install diffetent versions parallel or use virtualenv. There are some instructions to be found via google.

Comment: Are you doing an 'import os' in the wsgi file?

Answer (score 1):

Run 'ldd' on the mod_wsgi.so.

The problem is likely that it is finding a different Python version. It can also be that since your Python is not in a standard location, that it doesn't know where to find the installation.

In the latter case, add at global scope, outside of VirtualHost, in your Apache configuration:

```
WSGIPythonHome /root/epd-5.1.0
```

The value should correspond to the value of sys.prefix printed from your Python when run.

```
import sys
print sys.prefix
```

Comment: now, i get this error while restarting apache :/  --> Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 202 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: libpython2.5.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: As per documentation at http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Unable_To_Find_Python_Shared_Library set LD_RUN_PATH environment variable to directory containing Python library so can be found at runtime since not in standard location. LD_RUN_PATH=/root/epd-5.1.0/lib make

Answer (score 0):

Based on the errors you've got, it seems like a couple of things could be going on. Rather than throwing all this into comments, however, I'll go ahead and post as an answer.

In my django.wsgi file I have the following two lines that change the PATH environment variable to let python import packages from my django project:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/mysite.com/app/mydjangoproject')
```

You'll also want to make sure you add the following in your `httpd.conf` inside the `VirtualHost` that will you will be using django with:

```
<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/app/mydjangoproject>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

EDIT:

With regard to the symbolic link that you mention in your comments that appears in the error messages, I'm not quite sure what to make of it. If you are just trying to use it to allow apache to access resources that are outside of the DocumentRoot, you'll want to add the `Options FollowSymLinks` directive for `Directory` that contains the symbolic link

Comment: i was thinking just to remove the sym links, it points in an inexistent file.

Comment: I would say go ahead, by all means. It sounds like whatever intent it was created with originally is no longer relevant if it points @ nothing.

Comment: [root@lts5srv1 ~]# ldd /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so 
--> libpython2.5.so.1.0 => not found ...